# No error while building the application but not working in phone

Tags: unity-game-engine

Using Unity I made and Build an android VR game and there's no error during and after the building process but when I run the application to my phone its not working. What will I do?

Comment: Did you add the scene in your build settings?

Comment: Ensure you have the correct permissions set also

Comment: Yes sir Peaker ..

Comment: What permission and how I set this ? Sir Carter